# CSS vertical-align text input field with adjacent text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertically align a text input field with the adjacent text, namely, with a heading that precedes it and a radio button that follows it (all styled with `display: inline`). Here is an image of what I would like to see:

[image]

Now, without a `vertical-align` property on the input field, I get the following:

[image]

I.e., the input field is lower than the adjacent text. Playing around with the possible values of `vertical-align` on the input field, I realized that `vertical-align: super` gives me what I want (i.e, what can be seen in the first image). But I do not understand *why* it gives me what I want. I would have expected that `vertical-align: baseline` or `vertical-align: text-bottom` would do what I need. So my question is this: Why does `vertical-align: super` produce the result that it does? Is it a coincidence that it gives me what I want (i.e., a workaround rather than the solution)? If so, what would be the proper solution?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
h1,
form,
div.search {
  display: inline;
}

input#search_string {
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" id="search_string" />
      <input type="radio" id="option" />
      <label for="option">Some option</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @CptKicks This is the default font of Firefox. I am not sure which one it is concretely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setting for vertical-align is indeed "baseline", and it also works that way in your example. What you are forgetting is that the baseline alignment doesn't align the bottom borderline of the input box, but the baseline of the **text** that is inside that box.  If you write something in there, you'll see it. (BTW, it's the same if you create a div with a border and text inside it.)

In the following snippet (which is almost identical to your code except that the alignment is not defined , i.e. default, i.e. "baseline") I added a `value` text  to the input tag, so here you see the baseline alignment.

```css
h1,
form,
div.search {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" id="search_string" value="here's some text" />
      <input type="radio" id="option" />
      <label for="option">Some option</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And I would say that YES, it's a coincidence that the `super` setting gives you something so close to the desired result that you see it as correct. `super` actually just means that the element is "raised" (sorry, i don't know the English word, but its like the number "2" in "three to the power of two").

I guess the safest way to achieve what you want would be to apply `position: relative;` to that input field, and a `bottom` setting to offset it from the default alignment. If you use the `em` unit in that (as I did below), it's relative to the font size, but to find an adequate value will still be a matter of trial and error:

```css
h1,
form,
div.search {
  display: inline;
}

#search_string {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" id="search_string"  />
      <input type="radio" id="option" />
      <label for="option">Some option</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```